# Is it possible to save the swagger url in a browser bookmark

Tags: url, swagger-ui

I am using swagger-ui and have different servers/interfaces/. So for each of them I store a bookmark - but the URL used in the swagger-ui is never ever saved within the bookmark. I always have to type in the address again.

Is it possible to save the URL used in the swagger-ui in a browser bookmark (for example as a special parameter)?

Comment: did you try out my answer?

Comment: Not yet. On holiday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your swagger-ui is running here:

```
file:///Users/me/work/swagger-ui/dist/index.html
```

And your server is running here:

```
http://localhost:8080/api-docs
```

Then you can bookmark the swagger-ui for your server like so (a simple GET with a param named "url"):

```
file:///Users/me/work/swagger-ui/dist/index.html?url=http://localhost:8080/api-docs
```

Comment: Not sure why it would work for me and not for you. Which version of swagger-ui are you using? What browser are you using?